# How to download file directly from browser with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, download

I'm trying to create an application that downloads file from URL after a JSON parsing, but it's downloading the file inside the application directory and not in the download folder of the clients.
Can someone helps me to understand how to do that?

Here's my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSteamingFile() throws Exception { //get method

  File f = new File("t1.csv");

  if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){

    try {

         URLConnection openConnection = new URL("https://www.dati.gov.it/api/3/action/package_show?id=537c1138-4c5f-41bb-aec8-862954b67b28").openConnection();
         openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
         InputStream in = openConnection.getInputStream();

         String data = "";
         String line = "";
         try {
           InputStreamReader inR = new InputStreamReader(in);
           BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(inR);

           while (( line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
               data+=line;
               System.out.println(line);
           }

         } finally {
           in.close();
         }

        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(data); 
        JSONObject objI = (JSONObject) (obj.get("result"));
        JSONArray objA = (JSONArray) (objI.get("resources"));

        for(Object o: objA){ //json parse to get the url
            if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject o1 = (JSONObject)o; 
                String format = (String)o1.get("format");
                String urlA = (String)o1.get("url");
                urlA = urlA.replaceAll("&amp;","&");
                URL urlD = new URL (urlA);
                System.out.println(format + " | " + urlD);
                if(format.equals("csv")) {
                    File fname = new File ("t1.csv");
                    download(urlD, fname);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "OK" );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  else System.out.println("File presente, impossibile scaricare");

  return "index";}

public static void download(URL url, File fileName) {
    try {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, fileName);     
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Errore di Input/Output" + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you have to make changes:

```
File fname = new File ("t1.csv");
```

Right now, as you can see, you pass filename exclusively (without any path). You just need to add path to your clients Downloads folder. Something like this would work for me on mac and linux:

```
File fname = new File ("~/Downloads/t1.csv");
```